# How to split data into train, val and test?

Tags: python, dataset

I am trying to split my cats and dogs dataset into train, validation and test sets with a 0.8, 0.1, 0.1 split, I've made this function to do it.

```
def split_data(main_dir, training_dir, validation_dir, test_dir):
    """
    Splits the data into train and test sets

    Args:
    main_dir (string):  path containing the images
    training_dir (string):  path to be used for training
    validation_dir (string):  path to be used for validation
    test_dir (string): path to be used for testing
    split_size (float): size of the dataset to be used for training
    """
    files = []
    for file in os.listdir(main_dir):
        if  os.path.getsize(os.path.join(main_dir, file)): # check if the file's size isn't 0
            files.append(file) # appends file name to a list

    shuffled_files = random.sample(files,  len(files)) # shuffles the data
    split = int(0.8 * len(shuffled_files)) #the training split casted into int for numeric rounding
    test_split = int(0.9 * len(shuffled_files))#the test split
    
    train = shuffled_files[:split] #training split
    validation = shuffled_files[split:test_split] # validation split
    test = shuffled_files[test_split:]
    
    for element in train:
            copyfile(os.path.join(main_dir,  element), os.path.join(training_dir, element)) 

    for element in validation:
        copyfile(os.path.join(main_dir,  element), os.path.join(validation_dir, element))
        
    for element in test:
        copyfile(os.path.join(main_dir,  element), os.path.join(validation_dir, element))
```

Heres the function call:

```
split_data(CAT_DIR, '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats','/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/cats', '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats')
split_data(DOG_DIR, '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs', '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/dogs', '/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs')
```

And here I list the directory lengths

```
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs')))

print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/cats')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/validation/dogs')))

print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs')))
```

Which gives the output

10000

10000

2500

2500

0

0

The function is splitting the data 0.8, 0.2 into the train and validation sets but I need it 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, for train val and test sets but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: why dont you use the tran_test_split function in sklearn its so fast and useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going wrong in the lines:

```
for element in test:
        copyfile(os.path.join(main_dir,  element), os.path.join(validation_dir, element))
```

It should be `test_dir` not `validation_dir` ...

Comment: Wow, bit of a blunder on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

other suggestion would be to use the ***train_test_split*** function on [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). This function split arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets. Please see my sample code below on how to use the function.

### sample code:

data before using the splitting function

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
#print length of X before splitting
print("length of X before splitting",len(X))
#print length of y before splitting
print("length of y before splitting",len(y))
```

### output:

[image]

### code:

data after using the splitting function

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
print("length of X_train",len(X_train))
print("length of X_test",len(X_test))
print("length of y_train",len(y_train))
print("length of y_test",len(y_test))
```

### output:

[image]

### Reference:

Please see this official [train_test_split documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for more details